# How to change color of a tab in Firefox Quantum?

Tags: colors, browser-tabs, firefox-quantum

I'm trying to change the color of one or more tabs (not necessarily the one that is currently selected). At least the color needs to be in the area where the tab title is displayed, not sure what this bit is called:

[image]

The Pre-Quantum Firefox addons don't work anymore, is there any other way to do this? The color does not need to be persistent between sessions. The end goal is to visibly group contiguous tabs so I can easily differentiate between tab groups.

Note: I'm already using tree style etc. but I want the distinction in the tab bar as well.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 thanks...  so at the moment there is no answer/solution...  not good, but good to know!

Comment: Tree Style Tabs apparently makes use of the new Containers feature.  I'm not that familiar with it, but you can directly play with containers.  That might be a path to grouping on the top.  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers?as=u&utm_source=inproduct

Comment: thx, I'll have to look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using the Microsoft Edge Browser. Here you can add tabs to a group and assign a color:

[image]

There are several add-ons for Firefox that mimic this behavior, unfortunately in my case, they cause a conflict with one of my other add-ons, but I hope this will help other users.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method to control tab appearance is with [*userChrome.css*](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes). How to Geek has a brief [tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/334716/how-to-customize-firefoxs-user-interface-with-userchrome.css/). The code below changes the color of the *active* tab and that of the tab where the mouse hovers to gradients.

`/* Tab: selected colors */`

`#tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab[selected] .tab-content { background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#88FF88,#FF88FF) !important; }`

`/* Tab: hovered colors */`

`#tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab:hover:not([selected]) .tab-content {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#FFFFFF,#888888) !important; }`

There is also the [*Colorful Tabs*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorfultabs/) extension.

Comment: I tried the Colorful Tabs extension, but as far as I understood it colors the tabs automatically, there is no way to assign a specific colour to an individual tab / to a group / to all tabs?!

Comment: I tried to edit the userChrome.css, the test worked well, thanks. Although I'm not sure you're code does what I want. I want to change the color for example of a specific tab out of all the tabs that are currently open. The code you posted does not do that, does it!?

Comment: Regrettably, no... I don't know of a way to change the color of a *particular* tab, after they're loaded, other than those hovered or active. BTW, it would be useful to *raise* a tab, i.e. make it active, on hover, as Tab Mix Plus did -- but I believe that is no longer possible since the Quantum step backwards.

Comment: dsstorefile1 pretty much said it, no individual coloring, but if you have another idea I wrote down what the goal in the end should be (see question).